Must I create a model only within an app in Django, not in the project directly?
I created a project like so:
$ cd dj-container
$ django-admin startproject core .
$ django-admin startapp app1

This means that core.apps does not exist, but app1.apps does.
I want to create models under core, not app1 (some models that are nor app specific, but are project specific). I created a Country model under core, and on running makemigrations, I get this error: RuntimeError: Model class core.models.Country doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
Do I have to add core in INSTALLED_APPS? And then perhaps creaate core.apps and create the app label. I am essentially making the core an app, and I vaguely think this is a wrong approach. Or do I just add an explicit app_label in the Model? Or should I create a separate app just for my common tables?

The usual way is to create an app called shared or common and put common models in that app. Apps can use models from other apps.

I usually call my project config, and then have a common app for that kind of stuff. You can't put management commands in the project dir either, so common commands also need an app.

Sure. After reading this and some other stuff, I have started to follow these naming conventions: core for project and common for common app.

I wouldn't worry about downvotes. Although it is not a direct programming question, in my opinion it is on-topic and a valid Stack Overflow question.

To establish a premise, I’ll say this: based on how Django’s migrations framework is built, when you define the layout of your data i.e. models, you need to tell Django where those models are located so yes you must create a package and add a module “models“ in it where your models will reside. This package must be added to settings.INSTALLED_APPS. This will enable Django find those models.

Remember that when you run:
django-admin startproject project
You will get a directory project that contains an inner directory project which is a Python package with modules: settings, urls, asgi and wsgi. There is no restriction that this inner directory project can’t also be considered an application and have models, etc. This would require adding it to settings.INSTALLED_APPS.
References:

Django Models [django-docs]
Django Projects and Applications [django-docs]


Oh. So if I have core as my inner project, I can also make it an app my adding apps.py, models, views, management etc, and include core in settings.INSTALLED_APPS (which I normally wouldn't if it was just a project). Is this a common(ish) design pattern used in the Django world?

”Common” is opinionated.
